# shell script to remove duplicating keys in xml

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

any script that reads xml files

```
<string key="aaa" value="something1" />
<string key="bbb" value="something2" />
<string key="bbb" value="something3" />
<string key="ccc" value="something4" />
```

will result to

```
<string key="aaa" value="something1" />
<string key="bbb" value="something2" />
<string key="ccc" value="something4" />
```

Remove the next repeating keys without sorting.

Thanks

Comment: What structural guarantees do we have? Will all duplicates that need to be removed be siblings of each other?

Comment: Also, the fragment you gave isn't valid XML, since there's no root element. Do you need something that handles content that isn't really XML, or is the intended input genuinely a well-formed XML document?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 
it will mostly just the XML parent tag and then a bunch of string children with key and value. 

`<string key="apple" value="value1" />`

`<string key="apple" value="value2" />`

`<string key="banana" value="value3" />`

will be 

`<string key="apple" value="value1" />`

`<string key="banana" value="value3" />`

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that your comment answers any of my questions. (If the word "mostly" were removed, it would answer some of them, as this would ensure that all the children are siblings -- thus adequately describing structure).

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F' +|=' '!a[$3]++' xml      

<string key="aaa" value="something1" />
<string key="bbb" value="something2" />
<string key="ccc" value="something4" />
```

Comment: This knows nothing about XML syntax. XML provides no guarantees that each element will be on its own line; that "key" will be before "value", or that any of the other assumptions made by this code are correct. An XML document could have a carriage return between "key" and "value" items, or no newlines in the file at all following the root element -- one can't safely assume line-oriented input.

Answer (score 0):

To modify an XML document using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to delete any element containing a key where a preceding sibling has the same key:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//*[@key = .//preceding-sibling::*/@key]'
  <in.xml >out.xml
```

Unlike naive text-oriented approaches, this will never generate invalid output without also exiting with an invalid exit status [as when the input is not well-formed]: It is guaranteed to either generate well-formed output or exit with an error.